# AlarmManager firing at wrong time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I tried to do some task once a day using `AlarmManager` as in the following code.

```
 public void start_alarm(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=alarm_prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("alarm", "alarm");
    editor.apply();
    editor.clear();

    Intent start_alarm=new Intent(MainPage.this,MailService.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(MainPage.this, 100, start_alarm, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000*60*60*24,pi);
}
```

`Alarm` fired no problem in that. But as in the code I set the alarm on `12:30 AM`. But above code triggers the alarm at `06:30 AM`. Am I doing anything wrong out there please notify me. I have set Alarms in my other app in `12:15 AM`. But it also fires at wrong time i.e., `06:15 AM`. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

For setting alarm at `12.30 AM` you can try this code.

```
// Set the alarm's trigger time to 12.30 A.M
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

instead of

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
```